# Making logs expire relative to the timestamp and not the indexing time(system time)

Tags: database, elasticsearch, ttl

I am using Elastic Search with a TTL for each index, and I have 1 index per day.

Now the problem is: I get my logs to expire , say 1 day(which I specify in the *default*.json) after the indexing, but what I want is the logs should expire relative to the timestamp of the logs(which I parse and replace the timestamp with) and not the time when the logs were indexed.

How do I do this?
Need expert help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it by enabling the [timestamp field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/timestamp-field/) and configuring its path in the mapping to point to a field in your documents. This would be the mapping:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "path" : "post_date"
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tried it myself but theoretically it should work, give it a try and let me know how it went!

Comment: How do I specify the path? I am having the timestamp in a field in the logstash export.... Do i need something like path:"@fields:ts", where ts is a field containing the time.

Comment: When i simply use "path":"ts" or "path":"@fields:ts", i get the error: Failed to parse doc to extract timestamp

Comment: That seems the way to go. Look at your log file and see what the parsing error is exactly.

Comment: My timestamp is of the form 2009-11-15T14:12:12.699Z. Maybe this creates a problem....when I use "path":"@timestamp", it should work ryt?

Comment: could you give me your mail id? I think u r the only one on SO who can help me with ES :P

Comment: There are quite some other experts around, I think it's more a matter of asking clear questions and doing some work yourself too if you want to get great answers.

Comment: I have already tried with all the fields possible..but I get a parser exception. Even specifying the data format does not help